# No nmap attribute 'PortScanner'?

Tags: python, nmap

Using Python 3 (with PyCharm as my IDE) and a Mac running OS Mojave (v. 10.14.6). I tried installing `python-nmap` using terminal command `python-nmap install`. Worked fine. However, when trying to use `nmap.PortScanner`, I keep getting this error:

> "AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'".

What can be done?

```py
import nmap

ns = nmap.PortScanner()

print(ns.nmap_version())

ns.scan('**IP Address goes here, not actually uploading an IP but I know it goes here, this isn't the problem**', '1-1024', '-v')
print(ns.scaninfo())

print(ns.csv())
```

Comment: The error says it clearly, the nmap module has no attribute PortScanner. so as the python-nmap module has that class, the only problem I see is that you installed the wrong package, maybe the nmap package or another package with a module named nmap. so try removing and reinstalling python-nmap again with pip install python-nmap

Comment: Already tried pip uninstall python-nmap and pip uninstall nmap and then pip install python-nmap, to no effect.

Comment: @mrgrizzlie I initially had the same issue as you. In my case I had done `pip install nmap` rather than `pip install python-nmap`... however once I installed 'python-nmap' and restarted my Jupyter notebook kernel I was able to `import nmap` and create an instance of `nmap.PortScanner()`. Maybe it is as simple as restarting your IDE?

Comment: use nmap.PortScanner without brackets